# SignalR winforms app using autofac not showing Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr, autofac

I Am new to signalr and just learning about autofac/dependancy injection. I have a solution that has a server with a hub, a client and some shared libraries.

The solution was working fine with the forms launching and the server starting and the client would connect.  I ran into and issue with the server restarts which took me down the rabbit hole of dependancy.  I started trying to use autofac to learn/implement DI but now neither the forms for the server and client launch but the solution runs without error.

I am stuck and have no idea how to troubleshoot to find out why.

the structure of my server app

Program (entry point)
IApplication (interface for the custom application class)
Application
ContainerConfig (CClass that stores the autofac config)
IFrmServer  (interface for the form class)
FrmServer

here is the classes in the server

each is its own class

```
namespace Beacon.Server
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            //load config into a variable
            var container = ContainerConfig.Configure();

            //define the scope of the application
            using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                //resolve the application to the custom Interface that has been created
                //this removes the application from the startup
                var app = scope.Resolve<IApplication>();

                app.Run();
            }

        }

    }
}


    namespace Beacon.Server
{
    public class Application : IApplication
    {
        IFrmServer _frmServer;
        public Application(IFrmServer frmServer)
        {
            _frmServer = frmServer;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            //initialize new instance of beacon DB in order to register to Hub Events
            TRS_BeaconDB _BeaconDB = new TRS_BeaconDB();

            _frmServer.Startup();
        }
    }
}


namespace Beacon.Server
{
    public static class ContainerConfig
    {
        public static IContainer Configure()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            //register any classes to their Interfaces
            builder.RegisterType<Application>().As<IApplication>();
            builder.RegisterType<PacketManager>().As<IPacketManager>();
            //builder.RegisterType<FrmServer>().As<IFrmServer>().SingleInstance();            

            // Using a TYPED parameter:
            builder.RegisterType<FrmServer>()
                   .As<IFrmServer>()
                   .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(string), "packetManager"));

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}



namespace Beacon.Server
{
    public partial class FrmServer : Form, IFrmServer
    {
        private IDisposable _signalR;
        private BindingList<ClientItem> _clients = new BindingList<ClientItem>();
        private BindingList<string> _groups = new BindingList<string>();
        private BindingList<string> _requestTypes = new BindingList<string>();

        IPacketManager _packetManager;


        public FrmServer(IPacketManager packetManager)
        {
            _packetManager = packetManager;


            InitializeComponent();


            bindListsToControls();
            //Register to static hub events
            TRS_Hub.ClientConnected += TRSHub_ClientConnected;
            TRS_Hub.ClientReconnected += TRSHub_ClientReconnected;
            TRS_Hub.ClientDisconnected += TRSHub_ClientDisconnected;
            TRS_Hub.ClientNameChanged += TRSHub_ClientNameChanged;
            TRS_Hub.ClientJoinedToGroup += TRSHub_ClientJoinedToGroup;
            TRS_Hub.ClientLeftGroup += TRSHub_ClientLeftGroup;
            TRS_Hub.MessageReceived += TRSHub_MessageReceived;
            TRS_Hub.RequestReceived += TRSHub_RequestReceived;
            TRS_Hub.HeartbeatReceived += TRSHub_HeartbeatReceived;
        }

        private void bindListsToControls()
        {
            //Clients list
            cmbClients.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cmbClients.ValueMember = "Id";
            cmbClients.DataSource = _clients;

            //Groups list
            cmbGroups.DataSource = _groups;

            //requests list
            _requestTypes.Add("Request Client IP Address");
            _requestTypes.Add("Request Client Alive");
            _requestTypes.Add("Request Client Add Numbers");
            _requestTypes.Add("Request Data");

            cmbRequests.DataSource = _requestTypes;

            //Bind the task list to the grid view
            TaskManager _manager = new TaskManager();
            grdTaskList.DataSource = _manager._taskList;
        }

        public void Startup()
        {
            try
            {
                //Start SignalR server with the give URL address
                //Final server address will be "URL/signalr"
                //Startup.Configuration is called automatically
                _signalR = WebApp.Start<Startup>(txtUrl.Text);


                writeToLog($"Server started at:{txtUrl.Text}");
                FileLogger.Info($@"{DateTime.Now} : Application Started");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                writeToLog($"Server unable to start:{ex.InnerException}");
                FileLogger.Info($@"Server unable to start:{ex.InnerException}");

            }
        }

    }
}
```

if there is any other code I need to show or other details please let me know

the whole point to this was to make sure that when the server restarted I could reconnect the client without restarting the whole solution.

CHeers

EDIT******

I forgot to include the startup class for the Hub

```
    class Startup
{
    //below methos works but has an issue with dependancy
    //specifically when the server restarts the client cannot find it
    //this is because there is no dependancy resolution code to handle these events

    //create signalr config on startup
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //CORS need to be enabled for calling SignalR service 
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        //Find and reigster SignalR hubs
        //By default SignalR uses GlobalHost, which is a singleton resolver. When disposed, it will never come back.
        //When creating the configuration for the hub, you should pass inn a new dependency resolver:
        //var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { Resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver() };
        //app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);

        app.MapSignalR();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few Pointers:

1. looks like  _frmServer.Show()  is missing in Application.Run which is responsible for showing form UI
2. hosting requires Admin rights if URL address is not added in URL access control list
3. I do not see any signalr hub configuration maybe it is available in startup class and looking at it would give more ideas.

If you think form.show is not required then object created from WebApp.Start should not be disposed of in order to have a successful hosting. looking at the code looks like forms object is disposed of hence hosting is also terminated.

Comment: Thank you for the response..... I added the Show() function and the Form attempts to start and then auto closes.... I just realised that there is no dependacy configure for the Hub.  I will try doing it myself but any advice is most welcome.

Comment: Also just to add to that it does hit the Hub Startup and start the hub.... but after that the app closes.

Comment: mbshambharkar.....after more troubleshooting and debugging I have found that everything is working its just disposing exactly like you said.  so now the question is why is Autofac leaving the using block in my Program.cs????

Comment: I did mistake,function should be ShowDialog() this will prevent from auto close. Thus your signalr obejct won't be disposed anymore. Regarding AutoFac, it is just DI container and it's job is not to control flow. Your application is closing because nothing is stopping it, here using Show()  form is shown but control goes back to calling thread which in the end terminates, using ShowDialog will stop the thread to proceed further untill form is closed, thus preventing termination of an app